# Why does my Spring Boot boot 5 times?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I am using Spring boot for my tomcat deploy of my webapp. On my mac, and on a fellow developers linux install (not sure of his distro), the catalina.out file has just one instance of the spring ascii art indicating that it booted up just once as expected.

On our development and production servers, both centOS and mirrors of one another, the catalina.out file has five instances of the Spring ascii art indicating that it is "booting" 5 times! I have code that runs in the `onStartup` method of my RestApplication that extends `SpringBootServletInitializer` and that code runs 5 times verifying that spring is booting up 5 times. Why is this happening on our production machines but not on our development machines? War files are deployed to tomcat 8 in all instances.

It takes many minutes before the webapp is ready as a result.

At first I thought maybe it was linked the number of clases tagged `@RestController` since that seemed about 5, but it turns out we have 7 classes with this tag. So, I can't find anything that would match up with this number of 5 boots.

Any thoughts? Cheers.

**UPDATE**

Here is my log file with an exception stack trace in the onStartup method. It is looking for a file of the name servletContext.getContextPath() + "_init.properties". As you can see we are alternating between a DeployWar with the name of "wildbook" (correct name of my war file) and a StartChild with the name of "". Except the last DeployWar does not seem to trigger a StartChild.

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:40:53 |
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:40:53 |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:40:53 |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:40:53 | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:40:53 |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:40:53 |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:40:53 |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:40:53 |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.1.RELEASE)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:40:53 |
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:02 | [WARN] org.ecocean.rest.RestApplication - Can't read init property file, building simple props from init params.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:02 | java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat8/conf/wildbook_init.properties (No such file or directory)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:02 |   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:02 |   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:02 |   at com.samsix.util.io.ResourceReaderImpl.addSource(ResourceReaderImpl.java:1182) ~[s6-util-1.0.6.jar:na]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:02 |   at org.ecocean.rest.RestApplication.onStartup(RestApplication.java:98) ~[RestApplication.class:na]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:02 |   at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:02 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:02 |   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:02 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:02 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:02 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:02 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:02 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1701) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:02 |   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:02 |   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:02 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:02 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:02 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:03 | [WARN] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - outOfOrder mode is active. Migration of schema "public" may not be reproducible.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:17 |
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:17 |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:17 |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:17 | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:17 |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:17 |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:17 |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:17 |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.1.RELEASE)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:17 |
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:24 | [WARN] org.ecocean.rest.RestApplication - Can't read init property file, building simple props from init params.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:24 | java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat8/conf/_init.properties (No such file or directory)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:24 |   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:24 |   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:24 |   at com.samsix.util.io.ResourceReaderImpl.addSource(ResourceReaderImpl.java:1182) ~[s6-util-1.0.6.jar:na]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:24 |   at org.ecocean.rest.RestApplication.onStartup(RestApplication.java:98) ~[RestApplication.class:na]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:24 |   at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:24 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:24 |   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:24 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:24 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:24 |   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:24 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:24 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:24 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:25 | [WARN] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - outOfOrder mode is active. Migration of schema "public" may not be reproducible.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:34 |
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:34 |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:34 |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:34 | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:34 |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:34 |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:34 |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:34 |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.1.RELEASE)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:34 |
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:40 | [WARN] org.ecocean.rest.RestApplication - Can't read init property file, building simple props from init params.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:40 | java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat8/conf/wildbook_init.properties (No such file or directory)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:40 |   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:40 |   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:40 |   at com.samsix.util.io.ResourceReaderImpl.addSource(ResourceReaderImpl.java:1182) ~[s6-util-1.0.6.jar:na]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:40 |   at org.ecocean.rest.RestApplication.onStartup(RestApplication.java:98) ~[RestApplication.class:na]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:40 |   at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:40 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:40 |   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:40 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:40 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:40 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:40 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:40 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1701) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:40 |   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:40 |   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:40 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:40 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:40 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:41 | [WARN] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - outOfOrder mode is active. Migration of schema "public" may not be reproducible.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:50 |
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:50 |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:50 |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:50 | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:50 |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:50 |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:50 |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:50 |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.1.RELEASE)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:50 |
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:55 | [WARN] org.ecocean.rest.RestApplication - Can't read init property file, building simple props from init params.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:55 | java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat8/conf/_init.properties (No such file or directory)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:55 |   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:55 |   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:55 |   at com.samsix.util.io.ResourceReaderImpl.addSource(ResourceReaderImpl.java:1182) ~[s6-util-1.0.6.jar:na]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:55 |   at org.ecocean.rest.RestApplication.onStartup(RestApplication.java:98) ~[RestApplication.class:na]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:55 |   at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:55 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:55 |   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:55 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:55 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:55 |   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:55 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:55 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:55 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:41:56 | [WARN] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - outOfOrder mode is active. Migration of schema "public" may not be reproducible.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:05 |
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:05 |   .   ____          _            __ _ _
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:05 |  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:05 | ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:05 |  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:05 |   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:05 |  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:05 |  :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.2.1.RELEASE)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:05 |
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 | [WARN] org.ecocean.rest.RestApplication - Can't read init property file, building simple props from init params.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 | java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat8/conf/wildbook_init.properties (No such file or directory)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 |   at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 |   at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 |   at com.samsix.util.io.ResourceReaderImpl.addSource(ResourceReaderImpl.java:1182) ~[s6-util-1.0.6.jar:na]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 |   at org.ecocean.rest.RestApplication.onStartup(RestApplication.java:98) ~[RestApplication.class:na]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 |   at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.1.4.RELEASE.jar:4.1.4.RELEASE]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5143) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 |   at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 |   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:714) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:917) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 |   at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1701) [catalina.jar:8.0.18]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 |   at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 |   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 |   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 |   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_11]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2015/09/30 19:42:13 | [WARN] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate - outOfOrder mode is active. Migration of schema "public" may not be reproducible.
```

**Second Update**

Here is my SpringBootServletInitializer in it's entirety as requested.

package org.ecocean.rest;

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;

import org.ecocean.ShepherdPMF;
import org.flywaydb.core.Flyway;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.samsix.database.ConnectionInfo;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class RestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    /**
     *  This method should allow you to start up the rest service from a compiled jar rather
     *  than having to make a war and stick it in tomcat.
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
//        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
//        mapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());

        return application.sources(RestApplication.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException
    {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);

        //
        // Uses default location of db/migration on classpath. You will find it in the src/main/resources folder.
        // OutOfOrder = true makes it so that if two developers create SQL in a different order and one somehow
        // gets applied to the database, the other's should too. This should only be an issue on development
        // databases and allows me to get other developers sql patches even if I've applied a newer one myself
        // locally. In production, everything should be fine.
        //
        ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = ShepherdPMF.getConnectionInfo();
        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();
        flyway.setOutOfOrder(true);
        flyway.setSqlMigrationPrefix("");
        flyway.setDataSource(connectionInfo.getUrl(), connectionInfo.getUserName(), connectionInfo.getPassword());
        flyway.migrate();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean(){
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(new MediaUploadServlet(),"/mediaupload");
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO, the most likely cause is that you have five copies of the app on your production servers. However, it's impossible to tell from the information you've provided. Can you share Tomcat's logs somewhere?

Comment: Unfortunately there is only one copy of the app in the webapps dir. I've added the logs above and now have noticed that there are actually 7 instances of it booting! Could this be due to the @RestController tagged classes?

Comment: Odd.  Could you be starting up your service multiple times in an `@Configuration` class?

Comment: Are you using the embedded tomcat locally on the dev machines that are working? Or are they also using a full tomcat?

Comment: Very strange. Can you share the entirety of your `SpringBootServletInitializer` subclass?

Comment: @xdhmoore: My ```SpringBootServletInitializer``` class is the only one annotated with ```@Configuration``` and it is now included above per @andy-wilkinson 's request. Also dev machines that are working fine are using a full tomcat.

Comment: @crowmagnumb just a wild hunch. But, is it possible for you to clean up all the temp folder and the deployment of all existing applications in the tomcat folder and then try to re-deploy the application again? I'm assuming that this case is the same with me when I'm trying to deploy my application in Jboss server which turns out that old application is not removed completely.

Comment: @kucing_terbang - In my restart tomcat script I always blow away the entire $TOMCAT/work directory *and* the unpacked warfile directory. whenever I restart tomcat. This is to avoid that same problem. Too often I've had tomcat using old code even when the war file is refreshed.

Comment: I can't see anything out of the ordinary in the servlet initialiser. Can you attach a debugger to Tomcat when it's starting up on one of your development servers to see why the initialiser's being called multiple times? Failing that, logging an artificially created exception from `configure` and/or `onStartup` might help to shed some light on what's going on.

Comment: I've added a stack trace (accidentally as it turns out but hey that works) and I've updated my question with the results of that. Had to overwrite my first Update with this one because my question length was getting longer than StackOverflow allows.  It appears to be deploying 3 times and trying to start a child twice. Any idea on that?

Comment: @crowmagnumb I'm experiencing the same issue - did you ever manage to solve this?

Comment: @Mr.AJ Oh man, sorry about that. You know I don't recall if I ever solved this as is because I long ago switched to running Spring as an app directly, thus using the embedded Tomcat, and not dealing with an external tomcat. It was not the simplest process but perserverance got me there and I don't have any of these issues anymore. I highly recommond it if its not too difficult for you. It involves using SpringApplication and running it directly.

Comment: @crowmagnumb I appreciate your reply! I think it is indeed related to the external tomcat. I'll look further into it, thanks!

Comment: Internet is filled with the same issue, and there is not a single clean solution. Its irritating